# How to run a sudo command on startup?

Tags: linux, startup, sudo

I'm trying to connect to my vpn on startup. I normally enter protonvpn c -f into command line.
I have tried the method of creating an rc.local file however it didn't work.
This is the code I have inside of it (I got this from a post about a similar issue):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
/usr/local/bin/protonvpn c CH-NL#1
exit 0
```

I also made the file executable with chmod +x.
Im running Kali 2020.1 if that helps. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

create a file ==>  /etc/rc.local

Open and Edit rc.local like below,

replace your command with **apt-get update** below

```
#!/bin/sh -e
apt-get update
exit 0
```

save the edit with **Crtl+X**

after that

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

then do a reboot and check
It should 100% work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work for ubuntu systems.

https://askubuntu.com/a/290107/1051584

Kali is debian based so I believe this will probably work as well.